# Roslaunch API refusing connection

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having trouble using the roslaunch python api in my scripts, which is quite boring.
According to http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage I should be able to use roslaunch in python script, but I'm always having this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "roslaunchtest.py", line 9, in <module>
    launch = roslaunch.scriptapi.ROSLaunch()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 61, in __init__
    uuid = master.getParam('/run_id')
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/masterapi.py", line 206, in getParam
    return self._succeed(self.handle.getParam(self.caller_id, key))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Is it normal that the simplest code isn't working ? Or am I doing something wrong ?
I'd like to find a solution for that, since I need to launch a few files, like the turtlebot minimal, 3d sensors, and autodocking script. If it's not possible in this way, is there a workaround ?

Thanks

Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196184/roslaunch-api-refusing-connection/) by [RayBor](https://answers.ros.org/users/20612/raybor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the same error if the `/run_id` parameter isn't set, or if a roscore isn't already running.

I suspect the roslaunch API isn't able to start a roscore if one isn't already running. You may want to try your experiment again, with a roscore running.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1